# Multi-site Live Preview not working in Craft 3

Tags: craft3, htaccess

In the multi-site Live Preview in admin panel show error in the console.

> Failed to load http://www.example.local/test: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'http://www.example.test' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

This has been implemented for the upcoming Craft 3.1 release.

---

Currently Live Preview will only work across sub-domains (i.e. site1.domain.com and site2.domain.com), not completely different domains (site1.com and site2.com) 
 Here's a guide on how you'd set that up: https://craftcms.com/guides/using-live-preview-across-multiple-subdomains

In order for it to work across completely different domains, https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/1521 will need to be implemented.

Comment: I am running Craft 3.1.18 and unable to use Live Preview on a multi Site. Admin url: domain.com/admin
Site A: domain.com - working live preview
Site B: domain.in - Error: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.domain.in/?token=sv4HhcvPB8XScTzDXY-pJn-wboiyLR9T' from origin 'https://www.domain.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'https://www.domain.com, *', but only one is allowed.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Were you able to sort this?

Answer (score 0):

I have updated to craft 3.1.7
I can only see live preview on homepage of add on domain. Other entries do not have live preview available